# Broad idea of Lubin Tate group laws.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

I am reading Formal groups, Lubin Tate formal groups from Milne's class field theory notes.

I understand that group law on a commutative ring is a power series expansion in two variables with some conditions.

Let $K$ be a local field and $A$ be its ring of integers. Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer of $A$ then we have a subcollection $\mathfrak{F}_{\pi}$ of power series in one variable $T$. It then gives some groups laws related to the set defined above. I do not see where we are leading to.

It would be great if some one can give some reference for an article on formal groups just like What is Reciprocity law article by  Wyman for Reciprocity laws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I suppose the important fact about a formal group law over $A$ is that it turns the maximal ideal $\mathfrak M$ in the integers of each finite extension $L\supset K$ into a group that’s a Galois module. Being suitably careful, you can even let $L$ be an infinite complete extension of $K$. In any case, this group may be very different indeed from the additive group $\mathfrak M^+$ and from the multiplicative group $1+\mathfrak M$. In particular, its torsion subgroup may give a very useful representation module for the Galois group.

Keep on reading. I can’t imagine that there are many better expositors than Milne, but people tell me that the original L-T paper is very readable. It seems to be available on [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970622).

Comment: Are you the Lubin, the OP is asking about?

Comment: Actually, he was asking about the paper, not the authors.

Comment: Sir, I am very happy that master himself responded to this question. So, you are saying $\mathcal{O}_K$ module structre on $\mathfrak{m}_L$ is the important fact. I have downloaded the paper. I will read that and ask you if i have any other questions. I also like Milne's notes :)

Comment: @Anonymous : Yes, He is the master whose result is what I was talking about.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, I am retired, and am happy to communicate with young mathematicians, subject to constraints of time. I have warned others, however, that they may find my mathematical language rather old-fashioned. I’m sure you can find my Brown e-mail address somewhere.

Comment: @Lubin : Yes sir, I have your email address. I will ask you once i have finished reading that paper. Thank you :)